# How to print the value counts of all the columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataset where it has 24 dependent variables. i want to count the occurrences of each value(class) in all  the columns.

I have used the following code:

```
for i in target_c:
    print(f'{target_col[i].value_counts}')
```

The output is as following:

```
<bound method IndexOpsMixin.value_counts of 0           0
1           0
2           0
3           0
4           0
           ..
13647304    0
13647305    0
13647306    0
13647307    0
13647308    0
Name: saving_account, Length: 13647309, dtype: int64>
<bound method IndexOpsMixin.value_counts of 0           0
1           0
2           0
3           0
4           0
           ..
13647304    0
13647305    0
13647306    0
13647307    0
13647308    0
```

The expected output is like this for all the columns.

```
saving_account
0                 13645913
1                     1396
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Like the output says, `.value_counts` is a method. If you want to see the result from calling it, then you need to call it. Otherwise you just see this stuff, which is how the method itself is printed.

Answer (score 0):

As @Karl Knechtel said, value_counts should be called from the dataframe object. So if your dataframe is df, you should use:

df.value_counts()

Answer (score 0):

Group by the class available column.sum those

```
import pandas as pd
df  = pd.read_csv('sample.csv')
df.groupby(['Target']).sum()
```